# Shopware 6 App - best practice to locate settings page

Tags: shopware, shopware6-app

We are developing an app that requires configuration/settings page loaded from external.
So we extend shopware admin via a custom module, defined in manifest.xml. We get it shown as menu item in the admin navigation [as you can see in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOhyy.png). But we are not sure that it corresponds to the best practice (if many apps will follow this way the admin navigation manu can become messy).

We would like to place it under Settings -> Extensions -> "Our extension" or under Extensions -> My Extensions -> "Our extension" -> 3-points-menu (we now that we can use config.xml to get entry "Configure" in 3-points-menu but we need external settings dialog). Is it posible for apps? Would be grateful for some hints.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for a generic extension configuration page is to create a "main module", that should be the entry point for every extension.

Refer to the docs on [how to it over the admin-extension-sdk](https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide/api-reference/ui/mainModule/) or the [traditional way over the manifest.xml](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/administration/add-custom-modules#add-main-module-to-your-app) file.